# Managing invariants in Clojure / Haskell

Tags: haskell, clojure, functional-programming, invariants

I have been comparing OOP and FP methodologies and I could not put my head around one thing in functional programming - keeping invariants in the data structure.

For example imagine the following requirements.

We have a list of projects and every project a has list of tasks and a list of assigned members. 
Every task can have a worker assigned to it but only from the list of project assigned members.

I can imagine how I can solve this problem in a OOP language, for example in Java, by adding required checks and exceptions, and this would lead in my opinion to more robust code.

But as the data is separated from the behaviour in FP, how should I solve the same problem in FP, say in Clojure or Haskell?

Comment: One thing to note, is that both Clojure and Haskell have immutable datastructures as the default. This means that no client can change the data after you have verified it, which means verification can be a simple pre-check on first submission, and doesn't require any special update methods or assertions on each usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very general, a lot of strategies could be used to solve related problems but, essentially, checking invariants (at runtime) is "equal" than in OOP

```
assign :: Task -> Worker -> Either String Task
assign task worker =
    if not (taskProject task) `containsWorker` worker
        then Left "You can't assign..."
        else Right $ task { taskWorkers = worker : taskWorkers task }
```

One common behavior is hide `data` constructor (as `Task`, `Worker` and `Project`), the OOP counterpart is write `private` constructors.

```
module Scheduler (
  Task   -- instead `Task (..)`
, Worker -- instead `Worker (..)`
...
, assign
, createTask
, createWorker
...
) where
```

(I unkown the current Haskell support to `friend`, `protected`, ... counterpart probably not exists and you can find a lot of Haskell modules with `Some.Module.Internals.Something` with private objects)

The main question is about how to structure the whole program to achieve the required behavior.

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) is a good starting point to learn about that or as suggested on related question [Large-scale design in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077866/large-scale-design-in-haskell)

On the other hand, about pre/post condition in Haskell you can read [What are the options for precondition checking in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880137/what-are-the-options-for-precondition-checking-in-haskell).

Comment: In this example I understand that when I have a Task, I can write my own assign function and create invalid variant of Task?

My questions is that in OOP I can give out (return) a Task (object) and when it is properly implemented, I can assume that invalid modifications of its state are not possible.

Of course, in FP, one does not change the (internal) state of a variable, but can I also prevent a new variable derived from it to be in consistent state?

Comment: "can I also", yes, multiple encapsulations ways exists; the @MathematicalOrchid response point to it (I updated response).

Answer (score 4):

In Clojure it is possible to specify arbitrary `:pre` and `:post` conditions on any function. Here's an example from the [documentation](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc10):

```
(defn constrained-sqr [x]
    {:pre  [(pos? x)]
     :post [(> % 16), (< % 225)]}
    (* x x))
```

There's also a very interesting library [core.contracts](https://github.com/clojure/core.contracts) that implements [contracts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) in Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

You say data is "separated" from behavior in an FP language, but in Haskell (I don't know Clojure) you can quite easily define a data structure in a module, make its definition private, and only export functions to manipulate the data.

In other words, Haskell doesn't have (OO-style) classes, but it still has *encapsulation*.

Comment: Ok, but how could I get data out of the module when I want for example evaluate the data, say for example print out the list of project tasks?

Will I have to export a different data structure for that purposes?

Comment: You can export the data structure but not its internal structure. Which is rather like having a class with private members. Except it's called a module, not a class.

Answer (score 1):

JoseJuan and MathematicalOrchid covered key points about hiding constructors while exposing types and interfaces, but there is another technique for managing certain kinds of invariants in Haskell: encode them in the type system. Algebraic data types do this to a certain degree on their own:

```
data Tree a = Tri (Tree a) a (Tree a) a (Tree a)
            | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a)
            | Tip
```

is much more constrained than

```
newtype Tree a = Tree [a] [Tree a]
```

But you can go much further using nested types, phantom types, and GADTs. For example, `Data.Sequence` defines

```
newtype Elem a = Elem a
data Node a = Node2 !Int a a | Node3 !Int a a a
data Digit a = One a | Two a a | Three a a a | Four a a a a
data FingerTree a = Empty
                  | Single a
                  | Deep !Int (Digit a)
                    (FingerTree (Node a))
                    (Digit a)
newtype Seq a = Seq (FingerTree (Elem a))
```

Note that a deep `FingerTree a` contains a `FingerTree (Node a)`. This is called a "nested" or "non-regular" type; it ensures that the 2-3 trees at each level are exactly one deeper than the ones at the previous level.

The same shape invariant could be maintained differently (but less efficiently, as it turns out) using phantom types and GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- This is a GADT; n is a phantom type
data Tree23 (n::Nat) a where
  Elem :: a -> Tree23 Z a
  Node2 :: !Int -> Tree23 n a -> 
             Tree23 n a -> Tree23 (S n) a
  Node3 :: !Int -> Tree23 n a -> Tree23 n a ->
             Tree23 n a -> Tree23 (S n) a

-- n is again a phantom type
data Digit (n::Nat) a
  = One (Tree23 n a)
  | Two (Tree23 n a) (Tree23 n a)
  | Three (Tree23 n a) (Tree23 n a) (Tree23 n a)
  | Four (Tree23 n a) (Tree23 n a) (Tree23 n a) (Tree23 n a)

-- n is still a phantom type
data FingerTree (n::Nat) a
     = Empty
     | Single a
     | Deep !Int (Digit n a) (FingerTree (S n) a) (Digit n a)
```

In this version, the level of the finger tree is "tracked" using a phantom type, and then the heights of the 2-3 trees are forced to match it using a GADT.